# Brake Oil Production or Expiry Date?

Tags: oil

Ordered some brake fluid oil and it arrived today. There is only 1 date on the bottle. Is that date the production or expiry date?

My assumption would be production based on there being a what seems a time stamp of 14:25? Wouldn't make sense for there to be one for expiry? However just wanted to make sure.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not heard of brake fluid expiring.  If the bottle is open, however, moisture may get in and contaminate it.  So if using from an opened bottle, check the moisture content with a tester.  More than 3% is a problem.

An unopened bottle will last essentially forever, in my opinion.  So if what you are showing is an unopened bottle, use it.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with jwh20 about an unopened bottle. As long as it's sealed, it should be good.

What I disagree with is to use what you are going to use out of the bottle when you open it and don't save what is left. Since it absorbs moisture as soon as it is opened. Since it does that, it just makes more sense not to worry about the open bottle and discard it appropriately. This may seem like a waste, but in the long run it is definitely just easiest. You just don't have to worry about how much water it has absorbed. If you size your new container size according to the job at hand, you actually won't waste much in the process. When I do this, it's usually less than 10% of the total.